# How to remove firefox

Tags: applications, software-installation, firefox

[image]

I tried :

`sudo snap remove firefox`

> snap "firefox" is not installed

`sudo apt-get purge firefox`

> Package 'firefox' is not installed, so not removed

when I click at "Applications/Internet" I still see firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough points to ask in a commentary, but my guess is this:

If firefox can be uninstalled using apt or snap, maybe was not installed with either of those; maybe is a flatpack or an appimage. Or directly compiled from source.
Can my guess be a possibility?

cheers

Comment: I'm not really sure, when I installed the OS, it already have firefox.

Comment: It is strange that you can't uninstall an app. I just did "sudo apt remove firefox" and it disappear from my system. Maybe you may try remove instead of purge.

Answer (score 0):

using the command:

```
flatpak list --app>
```

check whether it is flatpak app?

if yes, use command below to remove:

```
flatpak uninstall --delete-data App-ID
```